# psycopg2 is mixing column names with values depending on the table selected

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I query a whole postgres table using

```
c.execute("select * from train_temp")
trans=np.array(c.fetchall())
```

and amid the expected data I got one row with the column names.

```
trans[-1,]
Out[63]: 
array(['ACTION', 'RESOURCE', 'MGR_ID', 'ROLE_ROLLUP_1', 'ROLE_ROLLUP_2',
       'ROLE_DEPTNAME', 'ROLE_TITLE', 'ROLE_FAMILY_DESC', 'ROLE_FAMILY',
       'ROLE_CODE', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

More puzzling is the fact the the number of rows returned match the number of row in the table

```
trans.shape
Out[67]: (32770, 19)



select count(1) from train_temp ;
 count 
-------
 32770
(1 row)
```

Here's the schema of the table

```
                         Table "public.train_temp"
       Column        |       Type       | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
---------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 action              | text             |           | extended | 
 resource            | text             |           | extended | 
 mgr_id              | text             |           | extended | 
 role_rollup_1       | text             |           | extended | 
 role_rollup_2       | text             |           | extended | 
 role_deptname       | text             |           | extended | 
 role_title          | text             |           | extended | 
 role_family_desc    | text             |           | extended | 
 role_family         | text             |           | extended | 
 role_code           | text             |           | extended | 
 av_role_code        | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_role_family      | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_role_family_desc | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_role_title       | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_role_deptname    | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_role_rollup_2    | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_role_rollup_1    | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_mgr_id           | double precision |           | plain    | 
 av_resource         | double precision |           | plain    | 
Has OIDs: no
```

What's going on here? Note it does not happen with all tables. Actually for this last one the process works fine

```
 Table "public.play"
  Column   |       Type       | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 row.names | text             |           | extended | 
 action    | double precision |           | plain    | 
 color     | text             |           | extended | 
 type      | text             |           | extended | 
Has OIDs: no
```

This last table is completely passed as string, while the  problematic one respects the data types.

```
play[1,]
Out[73]: 
array(['2', '0.0', 'blue', 'car'], 
      dtype='|S5')


trans[1,]
Out[74]: 
array(['1', '0', '36', '117961', '118413', '119968', '118321', '117906',
       '290919', '118322', 0.920412992041299, 0.942349726775956,
       0.933439675174014, 0.920412992041299, 0.976, 0.964478764478764,
       0.949222217031812, 0.909090909090909, 0.923076923076923], dtype=object)
```

Thanks for insight.

Comment: If you've solved your situation, don't put that in the question. Post it as an answer then mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just wrote the headers myself when importing the *csv into postgres.

I should have used the `header` option in `psql` such

```
\copy test from 'test.csv' with (delimiter ',' , format csv, header TRUE);
```